# Automapping SQL Server timestamp columns to byte[] using Fluent nHibernate

Tags: sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I am starting to use Fluent nHibernate on a project and am trying to get the automapping to work. At the time I am stuck with the mapping of our database's timestamp fields into byte-arrays. We are using SQL Server 2008 as the database, and we are not generating the database from code.

What I have:

```
public class Entity
  {
        public virtual Guid RowID { get; protected set; }
        public virtual byte[] ChangeCheck { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Data { get; set; }
  }
```

Our database convention is to name the version field 'ChangeCheck'. I cannot seem to locate where I override the default behaviour of DefaultAutomappingConfiguration to use ChangeCheck as the auto-generated version field.

Is it possible to get a DefaultAutomappingConfiguration sub-class to automap all ChangeCheck fields into version fields?

Thanks for any pointers and help.

### *Optional solution:*

Given I create an automap override for all entities using 'ChangeCheck' I could do the following:

```
 private class ChangeCheckVersionConvention : IVersionConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IVersionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Column("ChangeCheck");
            instance.Generated.Always();
            instance.UnsavedValue(null);
        }
    }

public class EntityOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<IssueReport>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<IssueReport> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Version(m => m.ChangeCheck);
        }
     }

 //....
 var persistenceModel = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<MyConfiguration>(new MyConfiguration())
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<MyConfiguration>()
            .Conventions.Add<ChangeCheckVersionConvention>();
```

Which works, however I cannot figure out how to remove the override to get the ChangeCheck column set-up as my Version column without having to override all my entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After not getting anywhere I decided to step through the Fluent nHibernate code to see what was happening. I then located how the 'DefaultAutomappingConfiguration' was setup, and created my own version:

```
public class MyAutomappingStoreConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override IEnumerable<IAutomappingStep> GetMappingSteps(AutoMapper mapper, IConventionFinder conventionFinder)
    {
        return new IAutomappingStep[]
        {
            new IdentityStep(this),
            new MyChangeCheckVersionStep(this),
            new ComponentStep(this, mapper),
            new PropertyStep(conventionFinder, this),
            new HasManyToManyStep(this),
            new ReferenceStep(this),
            new HasManyStep(this)
        };
    }
}
```

Note the **MyChangeCheckVersionStep** which is what is different. I then implemented a **VersionStep** class that added **ChangeCheck** to the list of column names that are assumed to be Version columns:

```
public class MyChangeCheckVersionStep: IAutomappingStep
{
    private static readonly IList<string> validNames 
         = new List<string> { "version", "timestamp", "changecheck" };
    private static readonly IList<Type> validTypes
         = new List<Type> { typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(byte[]) };

    private readonly IAutomappingStep defaultVersionStep;

    public MyChangeCheckVersionStep(IAutomappingConfiguration cfg)
    {
        this.defaultVersionStep = new VersionStep(cfg);
    }

    public bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        return validNames.Contains(member.Name.ToLowerInvariant())
           && validTypes.Contains(member.PropertyType);
    }

    public void Map(ClassMappingBase classMap, Member member)
    {
        defaultVersionStep.Map(classMap, member);
    }
}
```

The class basically calls the defualt **VersionStep** implementation for everything but **ShouldMap**.

Now I no longer need to create overrides for each entity to get the Version working. Note as well, that I still use the **ChangeCheckVersionConvention** - it is the override on every entity class I no longer need.